# error: failed to push some refs

Tags: git, github

tentando fazer um push para o repositorio e esta sendo rejeitado

```
$ git push origin master
To https://github.com/me/myproject
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/me/myproject'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: `Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not have locally` (...) `You may want to first integrate the remote changes (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

O problema acontece pois você está tentando subir commits para um git remoto, mas existem commits que você não tem no seu repositório local. Antes de fazer o push, você precisa puxar/pull os commits de lá:

```sh
git checkout <sua-branch>    # troca de branch
git pull origin <sua-branch> # puxa as alterações da branch no remoto origin
```

Se algum arquivo no remoto foi alterado por você no repositório local, você terá que resolver conflitos de merge antes de empurrar/push pro remoto.

---

Leia com atenção: se você não quer os commits que estão no remoto, e quer sobrescrever tudo que está lá com o seu repositório local, use o **comando destrutivo** abaixo:

> `git push origin <sua-branch> --force`

Answer (score 5):

Seu repositório local não está compatível com o repositório online.

Primeiro de tudo: retire os arquivos modificados por você e coloque-os em um diretório qualquer.

Depois de feito isso rode o comando:

```
git remote update #vai atualizar os branches locais com as cópias do repositório online
```

Em seguida rode:

```
git reset upstream/master
```

ou, caso não funcione com *upstream*, substitua por *origin*

Pronto, seu repô está atualizado. Agora volte com os seus arquivos modificados para o diretório onde você deseja e rede o comando:

```
git pull -r upstream master
```

ou, caso não funcione com *upstream*, substitua por *origin*

Isso vai trazer tudo de novo do master e colocar a sua mudança em cima. Daí é só mandar o `push` pro seu `origin/<branchname>` com `--force`.